# Change position to fixed when scrolled a number of pixels (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm quite new to query and would like to make three images overflow each other when scrolling down. I would like to let the first image move up until maybe half of it's height and then let the second one overflow the first one.

I have had a look at a few answers and came across this code, which works fine but it does not change the position of my div to "fixed".

```
var max_scroll = 300;


$(document).scroll(function(){


  if($(this).scrollTop() >= max_scroll)
  {
  $('#slideOne').fadeOut();
  }
 });
```

I have tried to replace .fadeOut() with

```
.css('position') == 'fixed')
```

but it does not work. I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: use `.css('position', 'fixed');`

Comment: Thanks! It works and the second picture flows over the first one but the first picture actually jumps back into its previous position. Is there any way to keep it in its half scrolled position?

Comment: I'd need a little more explanation of what your goal is here.  Maybe a link to the page or a JSFiddle for visuals?  Also a link to an example of your desired behavior would be useful as well.

Comment: I've seen the idea here, but doing it like that seems more and more difficult. https://www.airbnb.com/jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax as Deryck pointed out.

```
.css('position') == 'fixed')
```

Is checking if the position attribute of the object is fixed and returns true if this is the case. To actually change the attribute you have to call

```
.css('position', 'fixed');
```

I suggest that you take a look at the jQuery docs:
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: thanks. Is there any way you would be able to describe how they created this slider: airbnb.com/jobs ?

Comment: For advanced scrolling effects I would go with a library that lets you transform objects based on scroll position. The most flexible I have encountered so far is Skrollr http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/